# Find $g$ such that $\operatorname{div}g=f$ in the whole space $\mathbb{R}^d$. (Bogovskii operator lemma)

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, divergence-operator

For a fixed $f \in L^2(Q)$ with $Q$ a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$, I know we can find a function $g \in H^1_0(Q)$ such that

$$\operatorname{div}g =f \enspace\text{ in } Q$$
in the sense of distribution. This is only possible if we assume the compatibility condition :

$$\int_Q f =0 \quad \quad \quad (\star)$$

This theorem is also known as the **Bogovskii operator**, and there exist milder versions (with $f \in L^p(Q)$ essentially) that are well referenced in the book of Galdi, in the dedicated chapter :

Galdi, G. (2011). *An introduction to the mathematical theory of the Navier-Stokes equations: Steady-state problems*.

**I was wondering if the following is true** :

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, can we find $g$ (for exemple in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$) such that $\operatorname{div}g =f$ in $\mathbb{R}$ ? Is there a compatibility condition like $(\star)$ ?

Any references or help is welcomed.

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}^d$, you can simply Fourier transform the equation to get $\sum_j \xi_j \hat g_j=\hat f$ (up to some constants, depending on your normalization). In general, this doesn't have a solution in $L^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that $f \in L^{\frac{2d}{d+2}}(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L^2((\mathbb{R}^d)$ then the answer is yes (for some $g \in L^2((\mathbb{R}^d)$  : see Lemma 1.6.2 Chapter II in the book of Sohr - The Navier-Stokes equations: An elementary functional analytic approach.